# php internet explorer redirect header not working

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect, user-agent

im trying to redirect users to another page if they are using internet explorer but this code doen't redirect them it loads the page up as normal on i.e.

I have tried different variations of MSIE but nothing seems to work

```
session_start();

  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '/MSIE/i') !== false){
header('Location: /ie.php');
die();
}else{
echo "User Agent not recognised.";
}
```

any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
session_start();

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false){
    header('Location: /ie.php');
    die();
}else{
    echo "User Agent not recognised.";
}
```

The reason is that `strpos`'s second parameter, the needle, is not supposed to be a regular expression.

Comment: thankyou have tried this but is still not working in i.e, any ideas why?

Comment: shouldn't Location have an absolute path ?

Comment: @ninaj you don't really have to, the browser automatically knows. Just like html resources like images.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way in which you don't need php at all, and it's conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<?php echo "User is using Internet Explorer"; ?>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
<?php echo "User is using Internet Explorer 6"; ?>
<![endif]-->
```

etc...

Also you can get if the explorer is IE and if the version is lesser or greater than X:

Code if User uses IE and it's below version 9


Code if User uses IE and it's below than or equal to version 7


Code if User uses IE and it's greater than version 6

The advantages are that you can also pick the version of the browser, easy to implement, and you are using a little less resources from your server xD (although it would be a insignificant difference).

Another advantage is that you can use that to include css or js files in the header of your page depending on the browser.

The disadvantage is that you has less control as it's browser based(client side).

Comment: these if's will be executed browser side, so the php have no use here, as it will execute both paths

Comment: Yes the if's are executed client side, but they would still trigger the PHP code, it's just an alternative, I personally like to leave unimportant stuff to client side, there are situations in which you have to (like when using google maps api)

Answer (score 0):

Change `'/MSIE/i'` to simply `MSIE` and try it. Also, do you need the die() function?

Answer (score -2):

try to put **ob_start();** in top of PHP file